# is sqlite caching the results of the query for optimization?

Tags: python, sqlite, ironpython

I've noticed this behavior in sqlite. When I re-use the cursor object, the working set memory in the task manager keeps increasing until my program throws a out of memory exception.

I refactored the code such that each time I query I open a connection to the sqlite file query what I want and then close the connection.

The latter somehow seems to be not so memory-hungry. It doesn't increase beyond a certain point.

All I do with my sqlite db is simple select (which contains two aggregations) against a table.

Is this a behavior we can somehow control? I'd want to reuse my cursor object, but not want memory to be eaten up...

Comment: SQLite's own cache has a fixed size (typically 2 MB). This sounds as if some of your objects don't get cleaned up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

See [SQLite: PRAGMA cache_size](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size)

By default the cache size is fairly big (~2MB) and that is per-connection. You can set it smaller with the SQL statement:

```
PRAGMA cache_size=-KB
```

Use the negative '-' KB value to set it as a size in KiloBytes, otherwise it set  the number of pages to use.

Also, if using multiple connections you might want to employ a shared cache to save memory:
[SQLITE: Shared Cache](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the sqlite3 module for Python uses a statement cache.

You can read about the `cached_statements` parameter [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect).

More info on this [issue](https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/issues/126).