# Understanding benchmark of a Django view

Tags: django, caching, benchmarking

I am trying to measure the time it takes to query one of my Django views. It is basically doing a SELECT with different LIMIT clauses (sqlite). Here are the timings I obtain, first calling the view function directly, then calling it as a GET request with urllib.

```
LIMIT  view(s.)  request(s.)
25     4.5       12.6
100    1.6       2.1
400    3.5       3.3
800    4.4       4.7
1600   7.6       8.4
...
```

**Why is the first timing so high ?** Is there some obvious reason, like some cache that I could not disable, or inherent to database access ?

I am not using `cache_page`, and I tried to disable the cache overall, following some advice that I found on the web:

```
settings.CACHE_BACKEND = 'dummy:///'
settings.CACHES = {'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',}}
```

If I don't restart the server and run the test again, the 12s (first request call) becomes 1s as expected, but the 4.5s (first view call) remains the same.

Comment: You can try to understand the time-consuming operations by installing https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar.

Comment: If only I managed to make it work after 2h of attempts... :(( It does not like Apache proxy settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from Django's request cache, there is also the database query cache, the file system cache when you read the sqlite file, etc. However, I am not sure what disabling the caches would accomplish. They are part of the real-world request-response cycle.

If you want to know the efficiency of your database query, simply run the actual SQL query directly in the database console (`./manage.py dbshell`), using `EXPLAIN` (in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) and [Postgresq](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html), not sure about sqlite). That gives you a detailed list of the database operations and how much resources each step uses. So you could optimize from there.

Comment: Thanks. I need to know the worst-case timings, for instance what happens the first time a user connects to the app (and set up appropriate server timeouts). The query itself takes 0.01s. to execute, but putting the resulting QuerySet in a list takes seconds... Thanks Python. How can I disable the database query cache, just to be sure it comes from elsewhere ?

Comment: And it might very well be the db query cache, as I am evaluating several time the same QuerySet in my view.

Comment: Looks like sqlite really has a cache, size is adjusted with `PRAGMA cache_size=xy`, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15084273/5520354). If your resulting data is easily cachable, you could maybe load it on application start up, so you already have a cache on first request?

Comment: @muraveill putting it into `QuerySet` takes much time, because django will generate object for each record from database. Check `values` or `values_list` methods of `QuerySet` and use them if you can, it will make huge difference.

Comment: About 2x faster with `values_list`. The strange thing is that sqlite3 cursor `fetchall` also returns tuples, but another 2x faster than `values_list`. I map them to namedtuples afterwards (almost no perfomance loss).