# How to prevent sqlite from caching results when iterating over cursor

Tags: python, sqlite, caching

I am iterating over the result of a large SELECT statement (100GB of data) and realized that the results get cached when I iterate the cursor, up to a point where my memory is exhausted.

My code looks roughly like this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id")
for row in cursor:
   # do something
   pass
```

Is there any way of preventing sqlite from caching the results? I tried to set PRAGMA cache_size=0, but this does not solve the problem.

There is an old [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069937/is-sqlite-caching-the-results-of-the-query-for-optimization) which is similar, but did not get any useful answer.

Comment: Use `fetch()` in a loop?

Comment: you mean fetching result via `while True: cursor.fetchone()`? This causes the same problem as looping over the cursor itself.

Comment: Have you read [online docs](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size)?  It says "Whether or not this suggestion is honored is at the discretion of the Application Defined Page Cache. The default page cache that is built into SQLite honors the request, however alternative application-defined page cache implementations may choose to interpret the suggested cache size in different ways or to ignore it all together."  The Python sqlite implementation might prevent you from changing settings.  (You're using a layer above the Python library which likely defines certain options.)

Comment: Also, the `PRAGMA cache_size` is only a "suggested maximum" so sqlite will continue to allocate more memory as necessary.  Sqlite is not a remote server nor in a separate process.  Even if it is optimized, to some extent it must certainly need a minimum amount of memory to keep track of query results.  Something like "fetchone()" might make sense for a remote server since the python library itself could limit retrieval and in-memory storage to just one row at a time from the server, but if the server is local, then it cannot eliminate all memory usage.

Comment: Perhaps try other kinds of optimizations, like do you really need to request all columns (`*`) or can you be more specific to get only data you need?  Perhaps you can implement your own partitioning, limiting the query to sub-ranges of primary key values, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, C Perkins. The code in my question was meant to be a minimal working example. In reality I only select two columns (a numeric key and a text field) but the data I need to walk through is in the range of 100GB. I guess I could chunk the data manually, e.g. by using LIMIT and OFFSET, but this would slow down things quite a bit. I am surprised that sqlite gradually tries to load huge amounts of data into the memory, as this seems to defeat the purpose of an iterator for a on-disk database.